# How to persist ipvsadm configuration on Debian?

Tags: debian, networking, linux-kernel

`ipvs` timeout defaults to `900`s (at least on Debian)

```
ipvsadm -l --timeout
Timeout (tcp tcpfin udp): 900 120 300
```

Using `--set` I can modify the TCP timeout:

```
ipvsadm --set 3600 120 300
```

Is there a how to persist IPVS timeout after reboot?

`ipvsadm-save -n` doesn't seem to include default timeout values.

Comment: You can add the command `ipvsadm --set 3600 120 300` in the rc.local file. So that after every boot the timeout is set. Make sure you start the ipvsadm before that.

Comment: @RubanSavvy `/etc/rc.local` is being deprecated, but it was mine first idea as well. I'm not using `ipvsadm` service, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That timeout only matters if you use ipvs for something, how do you persist those settings, and can't you get the timeout setting in there?

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux with `systemd` best solution might be using `oneshot` service that comes up after setting up network.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/ipvs-config.service
[Unit]
Description=Configure IPVS
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ipvsadm --set 3600 120 300
RemainAfterExit=false
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

followed by

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable ipvs-config
```